# How can I push the data collected from IoT devices to Microsoft Azure IoT hub?

Tags: iot, android-sensors, azure-iot-hub, azure-hub

I need to connect my cell phone to the IoT sensors (Say BLEs) and collect the data which needs to be sent or stored into Azure.How can I do that? Is there any App (preferably mobile App) through which I can handle my IoT devices and push the data to MS Azure using any gateways? If yes, how can I do that? Links of any articles or materials and videos related to this will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such out of box mobile app to use.

If you like to develop an app by yourself you need [connect to sensors and collect data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) and [connect mobile device to Azure IoT Hub and send Device-To-Cloud message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java).

Also here is a Azure IoT and Mobile sample application: MyDriving. [It is a typical Internet of Things (IoT) solution that gathers telemetry from devices, processes that data in the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-solution-get-started). You can customize for your deployment.